# Shared preference value is not saved when closing the app

Tags: android

I have the problem that my Boolean value within SharedPreferences is not saved when I close the app completely. Unless I leave the activity within the app, the Boolean value is saved. Why is this the case and how do I change it?

```
private lateinit var sharedPref:SharedPreferences
private var permissionDeniedForRealTime = true


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

...
sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(
getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

}

...

override fun onPause() {
super.onPause()

 with (sharedPref.edit()) {
        putBoolean(getString(R.string.save_permission), permissionDeniedForRealTime)
        apply()
 } 
}


override fun onResume() {
super.onResume()

    val granted = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.save_permission), true)
    Log.d(TAG,"Persmission $isGPSgranted")

    if (!isGPSgranted) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission NOT granted!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
 }

//Here I set the value of the variable that should then be saved in SharedPreferences
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        permissionDeniedForRealTime = false
       
    }
    else{
        permissionDeniedForRealTime = true
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Change editor.apply() to be editor.commit() ?